# Why i don't have a correct answer for ro?

Tags: c++, while-loop

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    float pb;
    float N;
    float ro;
    float nb;

    printf(" Now we will find the number of charges and users \n \n \n ");

    printf(" Please enter the probability \n ");

    printf(" The probability is ");

    scanf("%f",&pb);


    printf("\n \n Please enter the number of circuits N \n");

    printf("The number is");

    scanf("%f",&N);

    while ( pb>0.01 )
    {
        pb=1/(1+N/(ro*pb));
        ro=ro+0.01;
    }

    printf("%f",ro);
}
```

Comment: Your code is probably wrong in some way, but we do not know what is the right code, because you haven't described what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

You need to, at least, initialize all variables that you don't read from the user. Right now, you are doing math using some "random" value.

Comment: the variables are only : N , nb , ro and pb

Comment: I want to ask the user to enter N and pb , then for a condition for pb , i will calculate ro ,, so pls help me

Comment: I don't quite understand your math, so I can't tell you exactly what your starting values should be. But surely, you don't want `ro` to have some completely arbitrary value when you start? And I don't see `nb` being used at all, so either you are missing something, or it's not needed.

Comment: My program is : I want to ask the user to enter the probability pb and number of circuits N ,, then I will calculate the charge ro ,, and the formula that contains ro is P=1/(1+N/(ro*p));       and nb is used to calculate the number of users , which is (ro*0.01) , but I don't write this formula now because I want to fix my problem before.

Comment: So, you need SOME initial value for `ro`. I don't know what a good initial value is - clearly not zero, since that would lead to "divide by zero". My statement of "I don't quite understand your math" was the same as "Saqlain's" statement on the answer below (which is essentially the same as mine) - neither of us understand what you are actually trying to achieve, but using `ro` without giving it SOME value is clearly incorrect. What the CORRECT thing to do is, we can't say without understanding what you are trying to solve in more detail.

Comment: okk ,, the given is :  while (p>0.01) , we apply the formula of P=1/(1+N/(ro*P)) and ro=ro+0.01  ,, this is all

Comment: Ok, so that will work OK if `ro` is all the values of 18.91271281 or 4112121121.3, -1817212.6321,  0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999.1, 6666666666666.8? Or ANY other value, when you start? Since that is what you are doing currently (It almost certainly isn't any of the values I've listed, since there are 4 billion possible values, and I've only given a handful). Surely, you need to start with `ro` being some good value, since it is involved in the calculation to begin with. I have no idea what a "good" value is, but you need one.

Comment: ahh okk , I understand you ,, so I'll check it in this coming days then tell you  ..    Thankk youuuu veryyy muchhh :D

Answer (score 1):

```
pb=1/(1+N/(ro*pb));
```

In your program above statement using ro and it is not initialized, so your calculation does not end up as per expected.

Comment: U mean i should write :ro=N/(1-pb); ??

Comment: To be honest i dont understand what you want to calcuate, there was issue in your code which i pointed out, but i would suggest to share exact problem statement along with your code, in that case we may help you in a better way, and it will be easy for us to see if your code doing exactly what it needed or not...

Comment: okkk ,, in my program I want to ask the user to enter the probability pb and number of circuits N ,, then I will calculate the charge ro ,,      and the formula that contains ro is P=1/(1+N/(ro*p));

Comment: you can calculate ro from P=1/(1+N/(ro*p)); using use ro=N/(1-p)

Comment: Yes you're right, and i write it in my first comment.  But if the user enter p=1 , ro will give an error.

Comment: Thankk youuuu veryyy muchhh  :D